# Return text from function cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to return extracted text in function. I'm extracting text but cannot return it to use in functions

```
    getAmounttxt() {
            cy.get('#product_price_1_1_0 > .price').invoke('text').as('ame')
            cy.get('@ame').then((ame) => {
                cy.log(ame)
            })
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use your alias as the returned value, it is there to help with asynchronous commands.

```js
getAmounttxt() {
  cy.get('#product_price_1_1_0 > .price').invoke('text').as('ame')
}

// in test
getAmounttxt();
cy.get('@ame').then((ame) => {
  cy.log(ame)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Cypress commands are asynchronous and thus do not compute a value directly, so you can't return a value from a function using a cypress command.

What you can do is return a Chainable and obtain a value within a `then` callback:

```js
    getAmounttxt() {
        return cy.get('#product_price_1_1_0 > .price').invoke('text')
    }
    
    it('test', () => {
       getAmounttxt().then(ame => {
          cy.log(ame)
       })
    })
```

Also, you can use an alias to transfer you values. Please look into [alias wrapper approach](https://medium.com/@NicholasBoll/cypress-io-making-aliases-type-safe-b6f5db07d580) if you want to have an alias represented as a real variable which can be passed through all your code.